# Scrolling issue - very difficult to "get to" the fields at the bottom of the screen

Tags: blackberry

I am experiencing a strange problem:  I have a Screen that is using the default VerticalFieldManager .... super( USE_ALL_WIDTH | USE_ALL_HEIGHT ); ..... whereby we add 24 additional fields.  These additional fields are of Types RichTextField, NullField, TextField, and ObjectChoiceField.  This screen is effecitvely just a CRUD form ... for entering data to be sent to a backend server.

What's interesting is the fact that I cannot use the little TrackPad (the real device and simulator are 9850 Torch 2's) to navigate down to the fields that are at the bottom of the screen.  As it is a Touch based device, I can "drag" the screen upwards to expose those fields which are at the bottom but only after the virtual keyboard has been displayed.

According to the MainManager.getVirtualHeight() method my virtual height is 970 pixels and my visible height is 800 (Torch 2).  The fields that are below the initial "viewable content area", and require scrolling to get to, I am unable to use the trackpad to place focus into one of those TextFields that are below the lower edge of the screen ..... point in fact, I might be able to place focus there but the screen still is not scrolling those lower fields upwards so that the user can see them.

It's a very simple implementation:

```
public class GetDataScreen extends MainScreen .....

public GetDataScreen()
{
    super( MainScreen.USE_ALL_WIDTH | MainScreen.USE_ALL_HEIGHT );

    add( field1 );
    add( field2 );
    ....
    ...
    ..
    .
}
```

Any thoughts on what's causing this or how to fix it?  For the record I have also tried calling:

```
super( MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLL | MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR | MainScreen.USE_ALL_WIDTH | MainScreen.USE_ALL_HEIGHT );
```

..... hoping that would fix it but it didn't make any difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay .. after allot of trial and error I did something (complete desperation) and it worked!  This is too dumb, and if it weren't for the fact that some other person might have the same issue I'd keep this to myself .....

I simply created a VerticalFieldManager that I added all the fields to, then added that VFM to the Screen.  Point in fact this should NOT make any difference - at all - as the default Manager on a Screen is a VFM.  Nothing else.  No other properties set, methods called, events .... nada.

Go figure.

Comment: Your case seems similar to one of mine that I've spotted about a year ago: on 5.0/9550, when screen contents are several screen-height tall, especially having browserfield inside, the VFM miscalculates the sizes, and couldn't scroll all to the bottom, with diff proportional to contents size. But, if you derived from VFM - this does not occur. Really, nothing more, just subclassed. A change from "mgr = new VirtualFieldManager();" to "mgr = new VirtualFieldManager(){};" did the trick. I've tested it thoroughly, and it was 100% deterministic bug in framework. Java users, go figure that one! :))))

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this problem on OS6+ when you have large TextFields on the screen - especially when a single textfield is taller than the screen itself.  If you break up the textfield into multiple smaller fields, it should help.

EDIT:
alternatively, you can write your own VerticalFieldManager, which was the ultimate solution I used.  Mine has some customization, but the core layout is not as complicated as you might think.  This doesn't do left/right/center alignment of the child fields, but you can add it easily enough if you need it.

```
public class MyVerticalFieldManager extends Manager {
    protected MyVerticalFieldManager(long style){
        super(
           style |
           ((style & Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL_MASK) == 0 ? Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL : 0) |
           ((style & Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_MASK) == 0 ? Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR : 0));
    }

    protected void sublayout(int width, int layoutHeight) {
        int height = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int lastY = 0;
        int lastBottomMargin = 0;
        final int fieldCount = this.getFieldCount();
        for(int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++) {
            Field f = this.getField(i);
            int margin = Math.max(lastBottomMargin, f.getMarginTop());
            final int x = f.getMarginLeft();
            final int y = lastY + margin;
            final int maxWidth = width-(f.getMarginLeft()+f.getMarginRight());
            final int maxHeight = height - y;
            this.layoutChild(f, maxWidth, maxHeight);
            this.setPositionChild(f, x, y);
            lastY = y + f.getHeight();
            lastBottomMargin = f.getMarginBottom();
        }
        this.setVirtualExtent(width, lastY + lastBottomMargin);
        this.setExtent(width, layoutHeight);
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your feedback - unfortunately, that's not it.  These are single line fields ... actually not even with content yet.  As about 1/2 the fields have a custom focus listener set (I change the border on TextFields when they have focus) it was suggested this might be the cause, but turns out nope.  Any additional ideas are very welcomed and encouraged - thanks Michael.